# show all datasets to admin user only CKAN

Tags: python, pylons, ckan

I am new to **ckan** , in this i need to show the datasets which are private and unauthorised and all other which are approved only to admin user, and for the normal user i need to show just approved datasets which is currently working , so please suggest me

`How can i show all datasets to admin user only`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

first you need to create an *Organization* (see the *Organizations* link at the top of the site). Then when you add or update a dataset, select the organization and select *Visibility: Private*. See: https://github.com/okfn/ckan/wiki/User-guide#creating-an-organization